# Best way to convert a Mongo query to a Ruby array?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Let's say I have a large query (for the purposes of this exercise say it returns 1M records) in MongoDB, like:

```
users = Users.where(:last_name => 'Smith')
```

If I loop through this result, working with each member, with something like:

```
users.each do |user|
  # Some manipulation to "user"
  # Some calculation for "user"
  ...
  # Saving "user"
end
```

I'll often get a Mongo cursor timeout (as the database cursor that is reserved exceeds the default timeout length). I know I can extend the cursor timeout, or even turn it off--but this isn't always the most efficient method. So, one way I get around this is to change the code to:

```
users = Users.where(:last_name => 'Smith')
user_array = []
users.each do |u|
    user_array << u
end
```

THEN, I can loop through user_array (since it's a Ruby array), doing manipulations and calculations, without worrying about a MongoDB timeout.

This works fine, but there has to be a better way--does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: I'm going to feel really silly if there is. Testing now @tokland

Comment: Yes, Users.where(:last_name => 'Smith').to_a works. Thank you +1... With Sergio's comment below, I'll be implementing his batch approach plus Ruby's native to_a instead of a manual loop. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your result set is so large that it causes cursor timeouts, it's not a good idea to load it  entirely to RAM.

A common approach is to process records in batches.

1. Get 1000 users (sorted by _id).
2. Process them.
3. Get another batch of 1000 users where _id is greater than _id of last processed user.
4. Repeat until done.

Comment: Good approach. And "greater than _id" supports the standard BSON format for _id?

Comment: Yes, objectids sort just fine.

Answer (score 0):

For a long running task, consider using rails runner.

runner runs Ruby code in the context of Rails non-interactively. For instance:

```
$ rails runner "Model.long_running_method"
```

For further details, see:

> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know about rails runner, I'm sure I can find a use for that somewhere, but not sure it will resolve any MongoDB-specific timeouts.